# Using FQL identify friends whose photos are private

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

My app needs to suggest to user friends who have visible photos (photos where privacy settings let them be visible at least to friends.)
I am trying to filter out users who did not make their photos public to their friends.
I know that the privacy table can identify the privacy settings for a specific object id

SELECT value, description FROM privacy WHERE id = 10150146071791729

How do I do it for all of the user's photos?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like you can get this result directly. You might need to do a batch query, first get all the album-ids that have been uploaded by the user's friends -

```
select aid, owner from album where owner in (select uid2 from friend where uid1 = me())
```

And then run the aid via the query you pasted above and eliminate the ones that are set to private.